# Stop and Starting MPMoviePlayerController by touch

Tags: mpmovieplayercontroller

I do a

```
  player.shouldAutoplay = YES;
  [player setEndPlaybackTime:initPlay];
```

and it works fine and then in

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
      if ([touches count] == 1) {
          [player play];
      }
    }
```

Even though the touch happens and the play command happens it does not work, but if I try and set the setEndPlaybackTime again it stil does not play? I just want it to keep play after the user touches the screen any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the video must rewind to the start? Have you tried:

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
  if ([touches count] == 1) {
      player.initialPlaybackTime = 0.0;
      [player play];
  }
}
```

See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

A value of -1 may also work.

Comment: No that does not work for me (0 or -1). But I do need it to continue from its current time, that's why I am setting the initial playtime.

Comment: Perhaps a use case providing complete problem and what should happen would help? The way I read it, you autoplay the video, it stops when done, and want to allow a touch on the screen to restart playback. Have you looked at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaPlayback_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfp/MPMediaPlayback/currentPlaybackTime ? The currentPlaybackTime property might help.